# SQL Server foreign key issue unit 3 assignment

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I am working on an assignment for school and I am a definite novice with SQL. I am trying to setup a foreign key relationship between data sets (i.e. IMDb Rating, Genre, Producer etc.) with movies being my primary key. I am getting the following error when I try to set the relationships between the table and column specification.

Screenshot:

[image]

Additional information as added in comments:

```
USE [Movies]
GO
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[Directors] Script Date: 6/12/2016 2:42:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Directors]( [DirectorID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL, [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL, [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_Directors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED( [DirectorID] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Directors] WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Directors_Directors] FOREIGN KEY([DirectorID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Directors] ([DirectorID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Directors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Directors_Directors]
GO
USE [Movies]
GO
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[Movie] Script Date: 6/12/2016 2:45:59 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movie]( [MoviesID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [Movies] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Movie] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [MoviesID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Seth. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then see if you can provide us with more information.

Comment: Hi Darwin, The assignment is to create a Database whose primary key is "Movies" with sub keys such as Genre, Producer, IMDb_Rating, etc. I have to link the sub keys (foreign keys) to the primary Key movies. It errors our with the above screenshot. Here is an exerpt from the assignment. We will create a Foreign Key for DirectorID, GenreID, ProducerID, and LeadStarID, linking the ID in the Movies table to the ID in the tables Directors, Genres, Producers, and LeadStar.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: The error message actually says it all - the columns `Directors.DirectorID` and `Movie.DirectorID` must have the same type and length to be used in a foreign key relation. Please post your **`CREATE TABLE`** statements and then I can tell you more. (PS: we generally prefer inline text over screenshots for such things. That way we can paste it into our own systems and run it if necessary.)

Comment: USE [Movies]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Directors]    Script Date: 6/12/2016 2:42:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Directors](
 [DirectorID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Directors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(

Comment: [DirectorID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Directors]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Directors_Directors] FOREIGN KEY([DirectorID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Directors] ([DirectorID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Directors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Directors_Directors]
GO

Comment: USE [Movies]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Movie]    Script Date: 6/12/2016 2:45:59 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movie](
 [MoviesID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Movies] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Movie] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [MoviesID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

Comment: Can you edit those into your question? Click the **`edit`** link right below the question tags.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the field first with the same size/type and only then create the relationship:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Movie] ADD [DirectorID] [nchar](10);
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Movie] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Movie_Directors] 
FOREIGN KEY([DirectorID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Directors] ([DirectorID]);
GO
```